# Unable to add mask to an image using both cv2 and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, mask, opencv

This is the original image:

```
plt.imshow(new_image)
```

[image]

This array was generated by a semantic-segmentation model :

```
print(image_mask)

array([[2, 2, 2, ..., 7, 7, 7],
       [2, 2, 2, ..., 7, 7, 7],
       [2, 2, 2, ..., 7, 7, 7],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])
```

When one plots this as an image using matplotlib it adds false colors and makes an image:

```
plt.imshow(image_mask)
```

[image]

To change it into an image i did:

```
image_mask_copy = image_mask.copy()
np.place(image_mask_copy,image_mask_copy!=15,[0]) # REMOVE ALL EXCEPT PEOPLE, == 0
np.place(image_mask_copy,image_mask_copy==15,[255]) # MAKE PEOPLE == 255
new_image_mask = np.expand_dims(image_mask_copy,-1)*np.ones((1,1,3))
plt.imshow(new_image_mask)
```

[image]

But when I try to do `cv2.bitwise_and` I get the original image again instead of an image with only the people...:

```
new_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image,new_image_mask)
plt.imshow(new_image)
```

[image]

And I get the mask when I try numpy..:

```
image_mask_copy = image_mask.copy()
np.place(image_mask_copy,image_mask_copy!=15,[0])
np.place(image_mask_copy,image_mask_copy==15,[1]) #NOTICE 1 NOT 255

new_image = np.multiply(new_image_mask,image)
plt.imshow(new_image)
```

[image]

I can't understand why this is happening... Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bitwise_and takes 3 arguments. cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2, mask)
```

and calculates the bitwise_and of src1 and src2 for each pixel that is != 0 in mask.

**https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html**

try

```
new_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image,new_image_mask)
plt.imshow(new_image)
```

instead of

```
new_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image,new_image_mask)
plt.imshow(new_image)
```

Comment: I am getting this error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /tmp/build/80754af9/opencv-suite_1535558553474/work/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:223: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'binary_op'

Comment: print(new_image_mask.shape,image.shape)
print(type(new_image_mask),type(image)) 

(720, 1280, 3) (720, 1280, 3)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>